# Babel does not compile typescript, looks like it is ignoring babel.config.js

Tags: typescript, config, babeljs

I'm trying to compile Typescript with Babel. I have `babel.config.js` in my projects root folder.

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    // https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#apicache
    // api.cache(true);

    return {
        presets: [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            '@babel/preset-typescript',
            '@babel/preset-react'
        ],
        plugins: [
            ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
            ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
            ['@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining', { loose: true }],
            '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator',
            '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
            '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
            ["babel-plugin-rewire"]
            ['inline-react-svg', { ignorePattern: /^(.(?!\.Component\.svg$))+$/ }]
        ]
    };
};
```

I run the following command

```
npx babel --config-file babel.config.js --out-dir build-test --extensions '.ts,.tsx' src
```

I get an error parsing Typescript:

```
SyntaxError: src/api/CarInsurance.Client.ts: Unexpected token, expected { (4:7)
  2 | 
  3 | 
> 4 | export enum InsurancePlanType {
```

It looks like the `babel.config.js` file is not being picked up, since nothing changes even if I throw an error in it's first line.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the problem was caused by a previously installed version of Babel 6.x, that somehow takes priority even after installation.

Solution: make sure you have local version of @babel/core and @babel/cli installed and call them explicitly.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli
./node_modules/.bin/babel src --config-file ./babel.config.js --out-dir build-test --extensions '.ts,.tsx'
```

Comment: it's also worth checking if you have the `babel-cli` (6) package instead of the `@babel/cli` (7) one